# sankey.layout() is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I am trying to follow the tutorial for d3 sankey diagram using Vue.js. However, I currently face an error saying that `Uncaught TypeError: this.sankey.nodes(...).links(...).layout is not a function`. Also, I cannot get dy, dx, x, y in `d.dy, d.dx, d.x, d.y` and it is showing that the values are undefined. Any suggestion on this? I researched and it seems like the newest version of d3-sankey does not have `link(), layout(), relayout()` functions.

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div id="chart">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
// import { sankey } from "d3-sankey";
import { sankey, sankeyLinkHorizontal } from "d3-sankey";
import sankeyMixin from "../mixins/sankey-mixin";
import { linkHorizontal, schemeCategory10 } from "d3";

export default {
  name: "SankeyItem",
  props: {
    data: Object,
  },
  mixins: [sankeyMixin],
  data: () => ({
    width: 700,
    height: 600,
    nodes: [],
    links: [],
    sankey: null,
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.updateSankey();
  },

  methods: {
    updateSankey() {
      this.sankey = sankey()
        .nodeWidth(10)
        .nodePadding(10)
        .extent([
          [0, 0],
          [this.width, this.height],
        ]);

      const formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),
        format = function (d) {
          return formatNumber(d) + " TWh";
        },
        color = d3.scaleOrdinal(schemeCategory10);

      const svg = d3
        .select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.width)
        .attr("height", this.height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(1, 1)");

      const path = sankeyLinkHorizontal();

      var energy = {
        nodes: [
          { name: "Agricultural 'waste'" },
          { name: "Bio-conversion" },
          { name: "Liquid" },
          { name: "Losses" },
          { name: "Solid" },
          { name: "Gas" },
          { name: "Biofuel imports" },
          { name: "Biomass imports" },
          { name: "Coal imports" },
          { name: "Coal" },
          { name: "Coal reserves" },
          { name: "District heating" },
          { name: "Industry" },
          { name: "Heating and cooling - commercial" },
          { name: "Heating and cooling - homes" },
          { name: "Electricity grid" },
          { name: "Over generation / exports" },
          { name: "H2 conversion" },
          { name: "Road transport" },
          { name: "Agriculture" },
          { name: "Rail transport" },
          { name: "Lighting & appliances - commercial" },
          { name: "Lighting & appliances - homes" },
          { name: "Gas imports" },
          { name: "Ngas" },
          { name: "Gas reserves" },
          { name: "Thermal generation" },
          { name: "Geothermal" },
          { name: "H2" },
          { name: "Hydro" },
          { name: "International shipping" },
          { name: "Domestic aviation" },
          { name: "International aviation" },
          { name: "National navigation" },
          { name: "Marine algae" },
          { name: "Nuclear" },
          { name: "Oil imports" },
          { name: "Oil" },
          { name: "Oil reserves" },
          { name: "Other waste" },
          { name: "Pumped heat" },
          { name: "Solar PV" },
          { name: "Solar Thermal" },
          { name: "Solar" },
          { name: "Tidal" },
          { name: "UK land based bioenergy" },
          { name: "Wave" },
          { name: "Wind" },
        ],
        links: [
          { source: 0, target: 1, value: 124.729 },
          { source: 1, target: 2, value: 0.597 },
          { source: 1, target: 3, value: 26.862 },
          { source: 1, target: 4, value: 280.322 },
          { source: 1, target: 5, value: 81.144 },
          { source: 6, target: 2, value: 35 },
          { source: 7, target: 4, value: 35 },
          { source: 8, target: 9, value: 11.606 },
          { source: 10, target: 9, value: 63.965 },
          { source: 9, target: 4, value: 75.571 },
          { source: 11, target: 12, value: 10.639 },
          { source: 11, target: 13, value: 22.505 },
          { source: 11, target: 14, value: 46.184 },
          { source: 15, target: 16, value: 104.453 },
          { source: 15, target: 14, value: 113.726 },
          { source: 15, target: 17, value: 27.14 },
          { source: 15, target: 12, value: 342.165 },
          { source: 15, target: 18, value: 37.797 },
          { source: 15, target: 19, value: 4.412 },
          { source: 15, target: 13, value: 40.858 },
          { source: 15, target: 3, value: 56.691 },
          { source: 15, target: 20, value: 7.863 },
          { source: 15, target: 21, value: 90.008 },
          { source: 15, target: 22, value: 93.494 },
          { source: 23, target: 24, value: 40.719 },
          { source: 25, target: 24, value: 82.233 },
          { source: 5, target: 13, value: 0.129 },
          { source: 5, target: 3, value: 1.401 },
          { source: 5, target: 26, value: 151.891 },
          { source: 5, target: 19, value: 2.096 },
          { source: 5, target: 12, value: 48.58 },
          { source: 27, target: 15, value: 7.013 },
          { source: 17, target: 28, value: 20.897 },
          { source: 17, target: 3, value: 6.242 },
          { source: 28, target: 18, value: 20.897 },
          { source: 29, target: 15, value: 6.995 },
          { source: 2, target: 12, value: 121.066 },
          { source: 2, target: 30, value: 128.69 },
          { source: 2, target: 18, value: 135.835 },
          { source: 2, target: 31, value: 14.458 },
          { source: 2, target: 32, value: 206.267 },
          { source: 2, target: 19, value: 3.64 },
          { source: 2, target: 33, value: 33.218 },
          { source: 2, target: 20, value: 4.413 },
          { source: 34, target: 1, value: 4.375 },
          { source: 24, target: 5, value: 122.952 },
          { source: 35, target: 26, value: 839.978 },
          { source: 36, target: 37, value: 504.287 },
          { source: 38, target: 37, value: 107.703 },
          { source: 37, target: 2, value: 611.99 },
          { source: 39, target: 4, value: 56.587 },
          { source: 39, target: 1, value: 77.81 },
          { source: 40, target: 14, value: 193.026 },
          { source: 40, target: 13, value: 70.672 },
          { source: 41, target: 15, value: 59.901 },
          { source: 42, target: 14, value: 19.263 },
          { source: 43, target: 42, value: 19.263 },
          { source: 43, target: 41, value: 59.901 },
          { source: 4, target: 19, value: 0.882 },
          { source: 4, target: 26, value: 400.12 },
          { source: 4, target: 12, value: 46.477 },
          { source: 26, target: 15, value: 525.531 },
          { source: 26, target: 3, value: 787.129 },
          { source: 26, target: 11, value: 79.329 },
          { source: 44, target: 15, value: 9.452 },
          { source: 45, target: 1, value: 182.01 },
          { source: 46, target: 15, value: 19.013 },
          { source: 47, target: 15, value: 289.366 },
        ],
      };

      this.sankey.nodes(energy.nodes).links(energy.links).layout(32);
      // console.log(this.sankey.nodes(energy.nodes).links(energy.links));

      var link = svg
        .append("g")
        .selectAll(".link")
        .data(energy.links)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", linkHorizontal())
        .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
          console.log("d.dy: " + d.dy);
          return Math.max(1, d.value);
        })
        .sort(function (a, b) {
          // console.log("b.dy: " + JSON.stringify(b));
          // console.log("a.dy: " + a);

          return b.dy - a.dy;
        });

      link.append("title").text(function (d) {
        return (
          this.nodes[d.source].name +
          " -> " +
          this.nodes[d.target].name +
          "\n" +
          format(d.value)
        );
      });

      var node = svg
        .append("g")
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(this.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")")
        .call(
          d3
            .drag()
            .subject((d) => d)
            .on("start", function () {
              this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
            })
            .on("drag", dragmove)
        );

      node
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height", function (d) {
          d.dy;
        })
        .attr("width", this.sankey.nodeWidth())
        .style("fill", function (d) {
          return (d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")));
        })
        .style("stroke", function (d) {
          return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2);
        })
        .append("title")
        .text(function (d) {
          return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
        });

      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", -6)
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return d.dy / 2;
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", null)
        .text(function (d) {
          return d.name;
        })
        .filter(function (d) {
          return d.x < this.width / 2;
        })
        .attr("x", 6 + this.sankey.nodeWidth())
        .attr("text-anchor", "start");

      function dragmove(event, d) {
        console.log("d.x: " + d.x);
        console.log("d.y: " + d.y);
        d3.select(this).attr(
          "transform",
          "translate(" +
            d.x +
            "," +
            (d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(this.height - d.dy, event.y))) +
            ")"
        );
        this.sankey.update(this.data);
        link.attr("d", path);
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    // colors() {
    //   return d3.interpolateCividis;
    // },
    // length() {
    //   return this.nodes.length;
    // },
  },
  // watch: {
  //   data: {
  //     deep: true,
  //     immediate: true,
  //     handler(data) {
  //       if (!data) return;
  //       this.updateSankey();
  //     },
  //   },
  // },
};
</script>
```